# Executing testng program, report throws java.lang.AssertionError

Tags: testng, report

```
try{
    text1 = driver.findelement(By.xpath("somepath")));
    Assert.assertTrue(text1.isDisplayed());
} catch (Exception e) {
    Assert.fail("text1 not found");
    Reporter.log("text1 not found");
}
```

I am implementing this code in testng, but in report it prints
java.lang.AssertionError: text1 not found
    at loginToGmail.composeMail(loginToGmail.java:86)... Removed 35 stack frames

But I just want "text1 not found".

Comment: That is the whole idea of stack traces, to provide more info.

Comment: I just want to print "text1 not found"..how to remove stack frames and assertion error.